# Owner of schema public changes depending on who I'm logged in as?

Tags: postgresql, privileges, psql

```
$ psql postgres

postgres=# \dn
        List of schemas
        Name        |  Owner
--------------------+----------
 information_schema | postgres
 pg_catalog         | postgres
 pg_toast           | postgres
 pg_toast_temp_1    | postgres
 public             | student
(5 rows)
```

When I log in to psql with user postgres, it shows that schema public is owned by user student. However, when I log in to psql with user student:

```
$ psql student

student=> \dn
        List of schemas
        Name        |  Owner
--------------------+----------
 information_schema | postgres
 pg_catalog         | postgres
 pg_toast           | postgres
 pg_toast_temp_1    | postgres
 public             | postgres
(5 rows)
```

It shows that schema public is owned by user postgres.

How can I get the ownership of schema public transferred to user student if the user with privileges to do so thinks that it's already done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding. You are logging into **two different databases**.

When running

```
$ psql postgres
```

`postgres` is the name of the database. With default configuration the name of the database user is derived from the name of the system user using [`ident` authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT) automatically. The only parameter is assumed to be the database name. You **do not** want to change anything in the database `postgres`, it's a system database for maintenance tasks.

The other database is named `student`. Each database has a schema `public` with its respective owner.

Read the [manual for psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) or try a lowly `man psql`.

To transfer ownership of the schema `public` in the database `student`, log in as superuser:

```
psql -U postgres student
```

Or as operating system user `postgres`, just:

```
psql student
```

And run:

```
ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO student;
```

[Details in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterschema.html) once more.